# How to get total count of items within a specific column in SharePoint 2013 List

Tags: list, sharepoint-server, column

I`m not a developer and looking for ways that would allow to get the total count of items within a specific column in SharePoint 2013 List.

Comment: Extend your question, where do you want to count (page? View?) and what do you want to do with the count. You are now asking a question similar to: I need a car.

Comment: @DannyEngelmanMPW, To my understanding in order to get the total count of items in a column, CSR can do the job.

Hoever, that will show the total a read only value either above the respective column name or at the bottom of the webpart.

What i`m after is to calculate the total of column 1, Total of column 2 (excluding Filed value set as "No")

Futher create a new calculated column in column 3 perform the following calculation
: calculated column 1 (full total) / column 2 (specific total excluding value set to "no")

Comment: @DannyEngelmanMPW, To my understanding in order to get the total count of items in a column, CSR can do the job.
However, that will show the total a read only value either above the respective column name or at the bottom of the webpart.

What i`m after is calculate the total of column1, Total of column2 (excluding Filed value set as "No")
Further create a new calculated column in column 3 perform the following calculation: 

calc column 1 (full total) / column 2 (specific total excluding value set to "no") * 100, to get the activity completed of the entire list. 

Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new view, filtered by your column equals your particular value. In the Totals section of the view configuration screen, tell it to count on any of the listed fields. Save the view. When you visit the view, it will be filtered and there will be a total at the top of the view that tells you how many items there are.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can i use the value to perform further calculation?

Comment: In that scenario you can't, it is just a display value.